# Android : JAudioTagger doesn't change the tags

Tags: android, id3, jaudiotagger

So I am trying to edit the tags of music files in my app. This is the code

```
TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);
AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(sel);
Tag tag = f.getTag();
tag.setField(FieldKey.TITLE, "ABC");
f.commit();
```

I have tried `AudioFileIO.write(f)` instead of `f.commit()` but the changes that I make are not reflected in the files. They still have the same old data.

I have tried a number of versions of JAudioTagger but no luck. Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit late but the following works for me (I use the same framework for the other tags

```
     public String getmp3TrackTitleTag(File SourceFile)
        throws Exception {
    String TrackTitle = null;
    try {
        MP3File musicFile = (MP3File) AudioFileIO.read(SourceFile);
        if (musicFile != null && musicFile.hasID3v2Tag()) {
            ID3v24Tag id3v24 = (ID3v24Tag) musicFile.getID3v2TagAsv24();
            TrackTitle = id3v24.getFirst(ID3v24Frames.FRAME_ID_TITLE);
        }
    } catch (CannotReadException | IOException | TagException
            | ReadOnlyFileException | InvalidAudioFrameException e5) {
        throw e5;
    }
    return TrackTitle;
}
```

and to set the title

```
      public String setmp3TrackTitleTag(File SourceFile, String strTrackTitle)
        throws Exception {
    String error = null;
    AbstractID3v2Tag v2tag = null;

    try {
        MP3File musicFile = (MP3File) AudioFileIO.read(SourceFile);
        if (musicFile != null && musicFile.hasID3v2Tag()) {
            v2tag = musicFile.getID3v2Tag();
            try {
                v2tag.setField(FieldKey.TITLE, strTrackTitle);
                musicFile.setTag(v2tag);
                musicFile.commit();
            } catch (KeyNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                error = e.getMessage();
            } catch (FieldDataInvalidException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                error = e.getMessage();
            } catch (CannotWriteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                error = e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    } catch (CannotReadException | IOException | TagException
            | ReadOnlyFileException | InvalidAudioFrameException e5) {

        throw e5;
    }
    return error;
}
```

Comment: I have reverted back to using the ID3 library for mp3 files. jaudiotagger does not really work for these files on android. Error of certain io files missing. Reading the issues list on github confirms this is an issue. Surprisingly editing  flac and m4a tags seems to work fine